# Special Characters in Vertical Text

Tags: flash, flash-cs4

I have a flash-application (done with CS4) in which a particular Textbox, which is vertical fails to display characters with a hacek (ˇ) on top. If such a character appears with in a string that is to be shown, it is simply dropped, leaving the string crippled.

This baffles me since characters with hacek work on other (horizontal) textfields in the same .swf with the same Font (Arial) work just fine. I also tried manually telling flash to embed these characters for this textfield, but to no avail. Even entering characters with hacek in the flash IDE works without problems.

I am not very familiar with flash, this application has been developed by a co-worker who is no longer employed here.

Is this a known problem? And more important: is there a fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have experienced similar problems with characters like ÅÄÖ when a filter, for example a drow shadow, was applied to the text. You can also try setting the anti-aliasing to "for animation" in the IDE, or to "normal", flash.text.AntiAliasType.NORMAL, in code (using "for animation"/"normal" can solve all kinds of strange problems with text in Flash).

Comment: Thanks alot. I have now idea why, but when I changed the AA-Setting to 'for animation' it did not work, but as soon as I changed it back to 'for readability' it worked! :)

Answer (score 0):

In order for a dynamic textfield to display non-alphanumeric characters when inclined at an angle the font must be embedded. If the text in your textfield is not changed during the operation of your flash program, your problem is solved by changing the textfield to a static textfield (Either with the flash IDE's properties panel, or by changing the TextField.type property if you're building the textfield with code).

Embedding fonts can be a real pain - try embedding the font using a library entry.
Assuming you're using the Flash ide:
Open the library panel, right click, and select "New Font".
Specify a name that is distinctive, and select the font you wish to embed. Hit OK.
Now in the properties panel for the textfield you will see an entry with the name you entered previously. In some versions of flash an * appears beside it. Select this one .